# usando o EntityManager para retornar um List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Galera, estou com um problema na hora de buscar no banco uma lista de telefones, esses telefones tem que pertencer a um CPF.

na minha query eu faço isso

```
public List<Telefone> buscar(Proprietario proprietario) {
      return this.manager.createQuery("select e from Telefone e where 
       e.cpfProprietario = :cpfProprietario").setParameter("cpfProprietario", proprietario.getCpfProprietario()).getResultList();
}
```

Onde estou errando?

A entidade Telefone tem uma relação com proprietário.

Caso precisem de mais informações, fiquem a vontade para chega-las no [github](https://github.com/danilodorgam/crud-jsf-jpa-hibernate-primefaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com JPQL as Query são feitas ao estilo OO, o seu erro e colocar e.cpfProprietario sendo que a classe Telefone não tem uma propriedade chamada cpfProprietario mas sim uma proprietario que contem o cpfProprietario.
O que pode estar te confundindo e que a tabela telefone tem uma coluna cpfProprietario.

```
public List<Telefone> buscar(Proprietario proprietario) {
      return this.manager.createQuery("select e from Telefone e where 
       e.proprietario.cpfProprietario = :cpfProprietario").setParameter("cpfProprietario", proprietario.getCpfProprietario()).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: verdade, acabei me enrolando com isso hehe